# Meteor Security: should all database insert, update, remove operation be a Meteor.call() to the server?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

Is there any performance hit of doing any database operation which involves insertion, update, removing of documents all on server side by calling the server method via `Meteor.call()` ?

Or is there a better way, or is it also possible to let Client do all of those operations on his side, and then send over that change to the server and broadcast it to all other clients?

My scenario involves the following: I want a reactive data table which automatically reflects when someone (logged in another account) or himself adds a new row, update a row or remove it. I have built an infinite scroll but the problem is when I go into a details page (clicking a row) and go back out, I lose where I was, I have to scroll my mouse wheelie down so that other documents may load.

Answer (score 1):

For the first point, you can choose any of the two possibilities, but i prefer to use the second one :

- Client can do insert/update/delete
- Server has some security checks

With this system you use the latency compensation of meteor. So it seems to be a good way of doing.

For the second point, you can imagine to store in Session where you are on the list when you click on the detail. Then when you come back to the list, you check the session value and you just have to use it to restore the state.

Comment: I'm not sure I quite understand the second part. Do you mean using sessions to make it reactive? I am already doing this.

Comment: Yes that's it. If you use it so it should work. But you have to use a router package to manage the history and the routing of your application.

Answer (score 0):

You can do both at the same time. This is one of those areas where Meteor's shared client/server code is really useful. Basically, do all the operations with `Meteor.call`, and store the call methods in a shared folder. That way, you get all the benefits of having the server handle it, and you still get to use the latency compensation. You can always use the [isSimulation method](http://docs.meteor.com/#method_issimulation), which will let you run client or server specific code inside the Meteor method.